# Gradle: Reuse black-box JUnit test suite in multiple modules implementing a shared interface

Tags: java, gradle, junit, junit5, junit-jupiter

I have created a java library module (named `sop-java`) consisting of a set of interfaces which specify an API. This module only contains interfaces, no concrete implementations.

In the same repository I also created another library module `external-sop` which provides an implementation of `sop-java`. This module can be used as a concrete implementation of `sop-java`.

Lastly, in another repository I created yet another implementation of `sop-java`, named `pgpainless-sop`. This module also contains implementations of the `sop-java` API and it can be used as a drop-in too.

Currently I have two distinct test suites, one for `pgpainless-sop` and one for `external-sop`, but I realized that it makes sense to merge both test suites into one, since expectations for both implementations are the same (both implement the same API which is derived from a specification draft). I believe they can therefore be called black-box-tests?
Further, it probably makes sense to have this test suite "reside" in the `sop-java` module.

Is sharing a test suite across different projects a thing? If yes, how would I inject my "test subjects" (the concrete implementation(s)) into the test suite? The entry point to the API is the interface `SOP`, for which I would inject either a `new ExternalSOP()` in case of `external-sop` or a `new SOPImpl()` in case of `pgpainless-sop`.

I read that with JUnit 3, you would create AbstractBaseTest classes and then extend those in the test sources of the concrete implementation, injecting the subject. However, I also read that inheritance in tests is not recommended anymore (and my test suite also will consist of multiple test classes, making it cumbersome to extend each and every one individually). Is there some kind of "TestSuiteInitializer" class which can set up a test suite by injecting test dependencies?

To add to the complexity, in `external-sop`s test suite I make use of `@ParametrizedTest` in combination with a `@MethodSource` providing multiple `SOP` instances already. Ideally the combined test suite would reuse this pattern, with `pgpainless-sop` then only providing/injecting a single `SOP` instance to the tests.

I am using Gradle 7.5 and JUnit Jupiter in my projects.

I hope it became clear what I am trying to do and I hope this question hasn't been answered using different vocabulary :D

My repositories are free and open source software:

- [sop-java](https://github.com/pgpainless/sop-java/tree/main/sop-java) (API definition)
- [external-sop](https://github.com/pgpainless/sop-java/tree/main/external-sop) (first implementation)
- [pgpainless-sop](https://github.com/pgpainless/pgpainless/tree/main/pgpainless-sop) (second implementation)

Comment: I think, generally put, the best practice is to test each unit "once".  That said, if there is logic in your interface, test that logic there.  If there is logic in layer 1, test that there.  If you are duplicating logic between layer 1 and layer 2, consider moving that logic to the interface...?  If you're copying code, you're breaking the DRY principle ("Don't Repeat Yourself").  If you're NOT repeating yourself, you don't need to test it twice, do you?

Comment: In my case there is no logic that can be moved to the interface. The implementations of the interface are vastly different (one is implemented using pure Java, the other one wraps a binary), so there is no shared logic between them. Still, since both implementations follow the same specification, a shared test suite makes sense in my eyes. Its only a question of how to share the suite :D

Comment: Since my issue might not have become totally clear, let me try to expain it with an anology: Let's say I wrote an interface "List", which follows a specification. Now I created two implementations ("ArrayList" and "LinkedList") which work differently, but follow the same specification. These implementations reside in different gradle subprojects. Now I want to have a shared test suite which checks the behavior of those implementations. For that reason I need to inject the implementations into the test suite which only depends on the interface, but does not know the implementations.